# logback AsyncAppender have performance issues intermittently

Tags: logging, logback, asyncappender

I am using logback AsyncAppender currently and it does reduce logging latency largely. However, I still spot some large latency intermittently. Check below two consecutive logging, the latency is 488ms which is unexplained

```
2023-04-24 05:42:05.446 [SofaBizProcessor-5-thread-4]   INFO[06023f5c168234012297211431566]search (rule,keyword) mappings with key: isContainerLink
2023-04-24 05:42:05.934 [SofaBizProcessor-5-thread-4]   WARN[06023f5c168234012297211431566]no (rule,keyword) mapping are present, try to match directly with key: isContainerLink
```

My logback configuration is

```xml
    <!-- neverBlock true means possible loss of logging events in case of full queue -->
    <appender name="ASYNC_MODULE_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="MODULE_APPENDER" />
        <queueSize>1024</queueSize>
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
        <neverBlock>true</neverBlock>
    </appender>
```

I am expecting no latency/blocking at all since I specify `neverBlock=true`

Any ideas?

Comment: Are those two log messages written one after another, or is there some code that executes between them?

Comment: @kdgregory it just has one line of code of `concurrentHashMap.containsKey(key)` to check if one key exist or not. And I believe this check won't cost 488ms

Comment: Right now, all that can be deduced from what you've posted is that two `LoggingEvent`s were created 488 ms apart. Event creation happens when you call `Logger.whatever()`. It's possible that your first event message took a long time to render (that is one thing that happens inside `AsyncAppender`), but otherwise it doesn't do very much (you can see the code [here](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/AsyncAppenderBase.java#L161).

Comment: Other possibilities would be external circumstances, such as a page fault, stop-the-world garbage collection, or losing time slice on a heavily loaded system. But with the information provided, it's impossible to narrow down the possibilities.